# Pivot rows to columns SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have done quite a bit of review here and have gotten close to what I need, but I am stumped on the last little bit (or so I hope).

I am using dynamic pivot to transpose my data from

```
DocID   PropID  StrVal  NumVal  DateVal
5938    21  TARRO, THOMAS A III NULL    NULL
5938    21  TARRO, JUDITH A NULL    NULL
5938    22  UNITED STATES   NULL    NULL
5938    27  NULL    NULL    2011-10-03 09:33:00.000
5938    28  Discharge Release   NULL    NULL
5938    29  NULL    1115    NULL
5938    30  207 NULL    NULL
```

To the required result of

```
DocId   21  22  27  28  29  30
5938    TARRO, THOMAS A III UNITED STATES   2011-10-03 09:33:00.000 Discharge Release   1115    207
    TARRO, JUDITH A
```

Here is the code

```
Declare @cols as nvarchar(max),
    @query as nvarchar(max)

Select @cols = STUFF ((select distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(FieldName)
                   from GrantorGrantee
                   WHERE tocid='5938'
                   FOR XML Path(''), Type
                   ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

Set @query = 'Select tocid, '+ @cols + 'from
        (
            select fieldname, tocid, FieldStrValue, FieldNumValue,    FieldDateValue
            from GrantorGrantee
         ) x
         PIVOT
         (
            max(FieldStrValue)
             for fieldname in (' +@cols +')
          ) p '

 execute (@query)
```

This piece of code populates the StrVal from the sample data, but I need to fill the columns with the respective data for each PropID...  whether it is string, value or date.

From the following data:

```
Tocid     fieldname         StrVal                 NumVal     DateVal
5938      Grantors          Tarro, Thomas A III    NULL       NULL
5938      Grantors          Tarro, Judith A        NULL       NULL
5938      TransactionDate   NULL                   NULL       2011-10-03 09:33:00.00
5938      InstrumentType    Discharge Release      NULL       NULL
5938      BookNumber        NULL                   1115       NULL
5938      PageRange         0207                   NULL       NULL
```

Can I use a case statement in the aggregate function in the pivot?  Is that the best way to handle?  I also have to handle the double value for propid = 21...

Thanks!

Here is the result of the code above.

```
Tocid  BOOKNUMBER Grantees Grantors  InstrumentType    PageRange   TransactionDate    
5938    NULL       UNITED STATES    TARRO, THOMAS A III Discharge Release 0207  NULL
5938    NULL       NULL             NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
5938    NULL       NULL             NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

So I grab the StrVal and populate the columns, but SQL doesn't know what to do with the DateVal and NumVal...  which is why I was thinking a case statement.

To test this entire concept of pivoting the source tables I did do some work with a static query before moving to the dynamic query

Here is a simple static query and result from a table in the database...  this is what I was using to test the concepts ...  the code above is using a View that I may or may not want to use...

```
select tocid, 21,22,27,28,29,30
from  (
    select tocid, prop_id 
    from dbo.propval
    where dbo.propval.prop_id in (21,22,27,28,29,30) and tocid='5938'
    --order by tocid
     ) x
    PIVOT 
    (
     max(prop_id) 
      for prop_id in ([21],[22],[27],[28],[29],[30]) 
     ) as p
```

Results in the following...  without column headers

```
5938    21  22  27  28  29  30
```

This gets me part way there...

The issue is that PropId 21 shows in two rows in the source table, I need it to show up in the resulting pivot as two columns.

Comment: If you can add the actual SQL generated and what it returns it'll be easier to help. Cheers

Comment: Why make it so difficult from the beginning? Why not write a *static* query first? Just assume some finite number of attributes and write a solution for those. To convert the result to a dynamic query, you'd probably just follow the same approach as with your single-column pivoting. "I also have to handle the double value..." – is that part of your question? Please explain how you want that handled. (It's not very clear from your example. Should multiple values go into the same row separated by some delimiter? Or different rows?) Also, you haven't really shown what you yourself have tried...

Comment: I have updated the post with some additional info...  thanks!

Comment: The columns that you are using in your query don't match the columns in your sample data, are they correct or can you fix them?

Comment: data added as requested

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way late, but if you haven't figured it out already, [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7561/3) is a SQLfiddle which does what I think you're asking for. Your column names still vary a bit from one part of your comment to another, so I had to make some guesses, and I did add 1 column to indicate the type of value for each propid. I'm sure you can probably figure out how to work it into whatever you're trying to do (if you haven't figured it out or given up already!) Anyway, if it's too late maybe it'll be of use to someone else.

Basically, I cast all the values as text so that the MAX() aggregate can operate over all of them and then cast them back to their correct types after the pivot using a string constructed in the same manner as your column string. Adding an additional ROW_NUMBER() to the first portion of the pivot keeps the multiple values for the same DocID & PropID from being aggregated into one. I wasn't sure whether or not the other fields were supposed to be repeated for the additional Grantor row, so I show doing it both ways.